# Python loading a text file line by line to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file in the following format where each line is separated by a line break

```
a 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566
b 0.013441 0.23682 -0.16899 0.40951 0.63812 0.47709 -0.42852 -0.55641 -0.364 -0.23938
c 0.15164 0.30177 -0.16763 0.17684 0.31719 0.33973 -0.43478 -0.31086 -0.44999 -0.29486
```

I'm trying to load the numerical component of each line into a numpy array of shape 3x10. This is the method I've been using.

```
embeddings = np.empty((0, 50))
for line in f :
            splitLine = line.rstrip().split()
            res = splitLine[1:]
            embeddings = np.append(embeddings, [res], axis=0)
```

However when the number of rows is increased (I have a text file with 400000 rows), this method become time consuming.

Is there a more efficient way to load the numerical values to a numpy array?

Comment: There are functions built in to Numpy to do this, I believe; any particular reason you're not using one of those?

Comment: Numpy.loadtxt does this

Comment: Yes, this is because `numpy` arrays are fixed-size, and `np.append` is a O(N) operation. Thus, using `np.append` in the loop becomes quadratic on the total size of the final array.

Comment: `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` read and parse the file line by line, but accumulate the results in a list.  The conversion to array is done once, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas' `read_table` instead, then convert the DataFrame to the numpy array you need. It will be faster and cleaner than trying to split strings and assemble an array row-by-row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because `numpy` arrays are fixed-size, and `np.append` is a O(N) operation. The best thing to do would be to load into a list, then use that list to create your `numpy.array`. If that list might get too large and give you memory problems, then simply use `np.fromiter`, it will be slower, but faster than your approach and more memory efficient than loading into a list. First, some set-up:

```
>>> s = """a 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566
... b 0.013441 0.23682 -0.16899 0.40951 0.63812 0.47709 -0.42852 -0.55641 -0.364 -0.23938
... c 0.15164 0.30177 -0.16763 0.17684 0.31719 0.33973 -0.43478 -0.31086 -0.44999 -0.29486"""
>>>
>>> import io
>>> import numpy as np
```

Finally, try to pass a `count` argument to `np.fromiter`:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with io.StringIO(s) as f: # fake a file
...     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
...     vals = (float(x) for row in reader for x in row[1:])
...     arr = np.fromiter(vals, count=10*3, dtype=float)
...
>>> arr
array([ 0.418     ,  0.24968   , -0.41242   ,  0.1217    ,  0.34527   ,
       -0.044457  , -0.49688   , -0.17862   , -0.00066023, -0.6566    ,
        0.013441  ,  0.23682   , -0.16899   ,  0.40951   ,  0.63812   ,
        0.47709   , -0.42852   , -0.55641   , -0.364     , -0.23938   ,
        0.15164   ,  0.30177   , -0.16763   ,  0.17684   ,  0.31719   ,
        0.33973   , -0.43478   , -0.31086   , -0.44999   , -0.29486   ])
```

Finally, change the shape to what you need, again, assuming you know the dimensions:

```
>>> arr.shape = (3, 10)
>>> arr
array([[ 0.418     ,  0.24968   , -0.41242   ,  0.1217    ,  0.34527   ,
        -0.044457  , -0.49688   , -0.17862   , -0.00066023, -0.6566    ],
       [ 0.013441  ,  0.23682   , -0.16899   ,  0.40951   ,  0.63812   ,
         0.47709   , -0.42852   , -0.55641   , -0.364     , -0.23938   ],
       [ 0.15164   ,  0.30177   , -0.16763   ,  0.17684   ,  0.31719   ,
         0.33973   , -0.43478   , -0.31086   , -0.44999   , -0.29486   ]])
```

If you *don't* know the number of rows ahead of time, you can do a quick-first-pass and count them, something like:

```
>>> with io.StringIO(s) as f:
...     num_rows = sum(1 for row in f)
...
>>> num_rows
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal loaders in `numpy` are `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`.  In this case both are easy to use:

```
In [129]: lines = b"""a 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688
     ...:  -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566
     ...: b 0.013441 0.23682 -0.16899 0.40951 0.63812 0.47709 -0.42852 -0.55641 
     ...: -0.364 -0.23938
     ...: c 0.15164 0.30177 -0.16763 0.17684 0.31719 0.33973 -0.43478 -0.31086 -
     ...: 0.44999 -0.29486"""
In [130]: lines = lines.splitlines()
```

Since you aren't interested in the first column we can skip it:

```
In [134]: arr = np.genfromtxt(lines,usecols=range(1,11))
In [135]: arr
Out[135]: 
array([[ 0.418     ,  0.24968   , -0.41242   ,  0.1217    ,  0.34527   ,
        -0.044457  , -0.49688   , -0.17862   , -0.00066023, -0.6566    ],
       [ 0.013441  ,  0.23682   , -0.16899   ,  0.40951   ,  0.63812   ,
         0.47709   , -0.42852   , -0.55641   , -0.364     , -0.23938   ],
       [ 0.15164   ,  0.30177   , -0.16763   ,  0.17684   ,  0.31719   ,
         0.33973   , -0.43478   , -0.31086   , -0.44999   , -0.29486   ]])
```

This reads the file line by line (simulated here with a list of lines), parses each and accumulates the results in a list.  This is faster than appending to an array each time.

To get better speed use the `pandas` reader - which has both C and Python engines.

```
In [140]: pd.read_csv(BytesIO(b'\n'.join(lines)), delim_whitespace=True,header=N
     ...: one,usecols=range(1,11)).values
Out[140]: 
array([[ 0.418     ,  0.24968   , -0.41242   ,  0.1217    ,  0.34527   ,
        -0.044457  , -0.49688   , -0.17862   , -0.00066023, -0.6566    ],
       [ 0.013441  ,  0.23682   , -0.16899   ,  0.40951   ,  0.63812   ,
         0.47709   , -0.42852   , -0.55641   , -0.364     , -0.23938   ],
       [ 0.15164   ,  0.30177   , -0.16763   ,  0.17684   ,  0.31719   ,
         0.33973   , -0.43478   , -0.31086   , -0.44999   , -0.29486   ]])
```

---

At least everyone claims pandas is faster - for this small sample it isn't:

```
In [141]: timeit pd.read_csv(BytesIO(b'\n'.join(lines)), delim_whitespace=True,h
     ...: eader=None,usecols=range(1,11)).values
1.31 ms ± 18.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [142]: timeit arr = np.genfromtxt(lines,usecols=range(1,11))
380 µs ± 17.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```